# How to count countires per unit of time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following problem. I have these data:

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": [
            "2021-11-30 00:01:08",
            "2021-11-30 00:01:10",
            "2021-11-30 00:03:08",
            "2021-11-30 00:10:08",
        ],
        "country": ["Czechia","Czechia","USA","Czechia"],
    }
)
```

I need to count how many times each country occurs in the dataset in each five minute. That is from `2021-11-30 00:00:00 to 2021-11-30 00:04:59` ; `2021-11-30 00:05:00 to 2021-11-30 00:09:59` etc. Countries should be transformed into new columns. Desired output is:

```py
output = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Czechia": [2,0,1],
        "USA": [1,0,0],
    }
)
```

How can I do this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
data["time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["time"])

    
df = (data.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='5Min', key='time'), 'country'])
          .size()
          .unstack(fill_value=0)
          .asfreq('5Min', fill_value=0))
print (df)
country              Czechia  USA
time                             
2021-11-30 00:00:00        2    1
2021-11-30 00:05:00        0    0
2021-11-30 00:10:00        1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `pandas.to_datetime` with `floor` then `groupby`:

```
data["time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["time"]).dt.floor("5min")
new_df = data.groupby("time")["country"].value_counts().unstack().asfreq("5min").fillna(0)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
country              Czechia  USA
time                             
2021-11-30 00:00:00      2.0  1.0
2021-11-30 00:05:00      0.0  0.0
2021-11-30 00:10:00      1.0  0.0
```